# Eclipse "Quick Access" to display recent tabs first?

Tags: eclipse, emacs

Can Eclipse's "Quick Access" (Ctrl+3) be made to sort the open tab names from the most recently visited to the least recently visited, a la Ctrl+F6?  The motivation here is to have one shortcut instead of two.  In emacs, 'anything.el' does exactly this.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the ["News and Noteworthy"](http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.3-200706251500/whatsnew/eclipse-news-part1.html) section of release 3.3 (search for "Quick Access"), I think that the intent of quick access is different. You here ask for any resource by providing some few characters, and eclipse helps here in numerous ways:

- It will remember what you selected last time, so it will order by last recently selected (not used).
- You are free to enter the characters, you may use whole words (anywhere in the thing you use) or the initials of the words you are searching for.

So it is a feature that the two actions work different, and by using only one, you won't reach what you want to get.

PS: Did not know `CTRL-3`, which is a nice shortcut if there is no keybinding to do menu entries, so thank's for that!!